# How to programmatically create Launch Screen through Xcode (without Xib assistance)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xib, launch-screen

I've been trying to figure out how to code up a launch screen that is not in Xib form.  Reason being, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do a decent job with Auto layout and constraint building.  Please do not suggest that I pursue that course of action.

I was thinking of implementing a custom `UIViewController` (with a Xib to hold just a reference to the view controller instance) that I could set with a black background and 5 `UILabel` subviews.  That Xib will be used as the "Launch Screen File".  I have the necessary methods to make sure the labels always resize properly given different device sizes.

However, is that even the right way to go about it?  I'm really trying to refrain from just creating a Xib and using that, or drafting up an image in Photoshop or something like that.

Comment: The launch screen is either a storyboard scene (without any code behind it) or a png image; it cannot be created in code since its purpose is to be displayed before your code begins to execute

Comment: Ah, nevermind then.  Thank you

Comment: Honestly constraints aren't that hard; there is a bit of a learning curve, but laying out 5 text fields sounds pretty straight-forward.